# How to prevent Windows 10 Software Center forced reboot?

Tags: windows-10, reboot

I have a Windows 10 managed machine and I want to prevent the forced restart requested by Software Center software.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to the post [stop-an-sccm-scheduled-reboot](https://systemcenterdiary.wordpress.com/2020/01/21/stop-an-sccm-scheduled-reboot/) by [@Peter](https://systemcenterdiary.wordpress.com/author/peterstorkprivat/).

0. Make sure you have administrator rights on the running windows. (If you don't this solution is not for you)
1. Download/Extract the sysinternals-suite https://download.sysinternals.com/files/SysinternalsSuite.zip
2. Create and save a **.cmd** file with the following contents

   ````
   taskkill /F /IM SCnotification.exe
   pssuspend.exe CcmExec.exe -nobanner
   shutdown -a
   ```
   ````
3. Run the windows terminal with administrator privileges, and from there execute the **.cmd** (I named the file stop-software-center.cmd)
   [image]
4. Check that the CcmExcec.exe process was suspended.
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

This just adds to acabra85's answer, but you don't need SysInternals Suite.

You can try stopping the CcmExec service from Task Manager > Services, I believe you need to have administrator rights for this.
This kills the SCNotification.exe as well (the window with the timer).

Run the `shutdown -a` command to abort the scheduled reboot (if any).

Comment: This worked, but after a while, the notification came back.  However, stopping the CCmExec service a 2nd time kept it away permanently, and the shutdown /a worked to prevent the scheduled reboot.